# Algorithm to simplify boolean expressions

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, classification, boolean-expression

I want to simplify a very large boolean function of the form :

```
f(a1,a2,....,an)= (a1+a2+a5).(a2+a7+a11+a23+a34)......(a1+a3+an).
```

'.' means OR

'+' means AND

there may be 100 such terms ('.' with each other )
value of n may go upto 30.

Is there any feasible algorithm to simplify this?

**NOTE:** this is not a lab assignment, a small part of my project on rule generation by rough set where f is dissimilarity function.

Comment: Since not all languages use that notation, can you be specific on what the `.` and `+` operators are?  I'm assuming OR and AND?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplification"?

Comment: If that's the case, then the primary means of "simplifying" are if there are terms that are in ALL OR groups that can be pulled out.  Other than that you may be able to reorganize but I don;t think there will be massive simplification.

Comment: The rule are static or dynamic?

Comment: By simplifying the function f we can generate at most one rule of the form    ai.aj.ak.al-> dicision   where ai,aj etc are condition attributes.

Comment: Have you thought about putting all the bits into an int (or long) and then doing f = a&19 == 19 | a&c == c | ... where & is a bitwise & and | is normal or (with early termination)? Simpler in that each term stays small.

Comment: @ Ian Mercer can you please explain it more?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form

Answer (score 4):

The well-known ways to do this are:

- if the number of variables is less than 5, use the [Karnaugh Map Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)
- if the number of variables is 5 or more, use the [Quine McCluskey Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm)

The second way is most commonly used on a computer. It's tabular and straight-forward. The first way is the best way to do by hand and is more fun, but you can't use it for anything more than 4 variables reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The typical method is to use [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) to reduce the statement to its simplest form.

If, for example, you have something like:

`(A AND B) OR (A AND C)`

you can convert it to a more simple form:

`A AND (B OR C)`

Answer (score 0):

If you represent the a values as an `int` or `long` where a1 has value 2, a2 has value 4, a3 has value 8 etc.:

int a = (a1 ? 2^1 : 0) + (a2 ? 2^2 : 0) + (a3 ? 2^3 : 0) + ...;

(wasting a bit to keep it simple and ignoring the fact that you'd be better off with an a0 = 1)

And you do the same for all of the terms:

```
long[] terms = ...;
terms[0] = 2^0 + 2^3 + 2^5           // a1+a2+a5
terms[1] = 2^2 + 2^7 + 2^23 + 2^34   // (a2+a7+a11+a23+a34)
```

Then you can find the result:

```
foreach(var term in terms)
{
   if (a & term == term) return true;
}
return false;
```

BUT this only works well for up to n=64. Above that it's messy.

Comment: yeah! I tried similar approach, but at the end I got a rule like, a1+a2+..+ak-> dicision, but I have to get the form a1.a2....ak->dicision, all the terms AND with each other, how to get it from here?

Comment: @sb15 not sure what you mean. The for loop creates the OR, returning true as soon as one of the terms matches all of its bits. In effect: result = a&term[0] == term[0] | a&term[1] == term[1] | ... a&term[m] == term[m]